# Ports used from traefik reverse proxy service are not reported from "docker ps" command

Tags: docker, traefik

The "docker ps" command does not show the traefik port 8080 and other ports used from the service

The traefik service is defined in a docker-compose.yml as follow:

```
...
  traefik:
    image: traefik:1.7-alpine
    command: --docker --docker.swarmMode  --docker.domain=mylocal.swarm --docker.watch --api --logLevel=INFO \
      --entryPoints='Name:http Address::80' \
      --entryPoints='Name:https Address::443 TLS'
    networks:
      - net-traefik
    deploy: *default-deploy
    ports:
      - "8091:80"
      - "8093:443"
      - "8080:8080"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
    logging: *default-logging
```

The "docker ps" command output is:

```sh
CONTAINER ID    IMAGE                COMMAND                 CREATED    STATUS        PORTS      
...
635a4e017bb5    traefik:1.7-alpine   "/entrypoint.sh o…"      …          …            80/tcp     
...
```

Why only the port 80 is displayed? I expected to find also 443 and 8080

Comment: What is the output if you run this `docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80 -v $PWD/traefik.toml:/etc/traefik/traefik.toml traefik`?

Comment: And then run `docker ps`...Note... before this make sure you have stoped the docker-compose containers

Comment: ```bash
# docker run -d -p 8080:8080 -p 80:80  traefik
bb5c46c778270209610c5662808675c5070cc70742abe139f46272e8c98a8a41
[root@srv1]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                                        NAMES
bb5c46c77827        traefik             "/traefik"               6 seconds ago       Up 4 seconds        0.0.0.0:80->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:8080->8080/tcp   dazzling_borg
```
  
  
In this case everything looks good. But in my case I am using traefik as a service running on a docker swarm

Comment: It mean, something wrong inside your docker-compose file.

Answer (score 0):

This port `80` is just the one that was specified under `EXPOSE` [in the Dockerfile](https://github.com/containous/traefik-library-image/blob/8c0a8508ea75d5a491abadb7fc5bfa33b2beb3d7/alpine/Dockerfile#L14) and therefore shows up there. The other ports you define in your file are mapped to the *service* you create with Docker Swarm, and not to a single container. If this would happen, then using Swarm at all is useless, because if you have more than one container – which is kind of the point of using Swarm – they cannot both be mapped to the same port.

[This blog post](https://blog.codeship.com/running-services-within-docker-swarm/) seems to contain some good information about how the publishing of services work with Docker Swarm.

Answer (score 0):

With swarm mode, the port is not published on the individual containers. Instead the port is published via the service, which then uses a VIP to send the request over the ingress network to one of the replicas of the service. You can use the following to see these ports:

```
docker service ls
```

Note in the `docker ps` command, the ports you see there include the "exposed ports" which are defined in the image. These are documentation from the image creator to the user of the image to expect something listening inside the container on this port, and in no way impacts published ports on the host or container to container networking.

Comment: Good point. I completely forgot that I should use the `docker service ls` command to see the port used from the service instead of the `docker ps` command